# Setting Dynamic Height to UIScrollView Swift

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, swift2, height

how can i set the dynamic height of **UIScrollView** based on the content/ subviews i have in my **ScrollView**

Here is what i am getting as output:

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We can use auto layout, where we use a content view in scrollview, which can be pinned to the scrollview and the height and width constraints given equal to the main view. Then if we want the height to vary dynamically we can give height constraint a low priority compared to the others and hence the content view's height will increase based on its intrinsic size, because of its sub views.

Reference Links:

1) https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithScrollViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH24-SW1

2) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6J22gHORk2I

Answer (score 4):

First you need set a subview height constraint of `0`, then calculate data height (which you want to set in subview), and simply assign `subview.heightConstraint.constant = data.height`, then you need to set `scrollView.contentsize` which is based on subview height:

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.scrollView.contentSize.width, height: self.subViewHeight.constant)
```

Comment: do you have any tutorial to follow @vaibhav

Answer (score 3):

for me this this trick worked (Swift 4)

```
scrollView.layoutIfNeeded()
scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: scrollView.frame.size.height)
```

Comment: Where do you call it / what does `self.view` represent?

Comment: @dv02 - best place to call it is in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method. Also, height should be set to `contentView.frame.size.height` rather than `scrollView.frame.size.height` because the scroll view frame is that of the main frame.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to build a scrollView with textViews (and other views), that had to size dynamically.
In InterfaceBuilder I set constraints for min. height and a fixed height. The fixed heigth is then removed at build time. 
This is working as expected.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

set equal width and equal height constraints of subview of scrollview to main view.
In IB Size Inspector, set Equal Heights Constraints - Priority to Low(250)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to  calculate the needed height for your content including spacing.
Assign that value as the height of the row and refresh the table (or part in it with the row)

Answer (score 0):

Example of vertical scroll view resizing regarding the length of its label's text:

```
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    scrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2).isActive = true

    let bodyLabel = UILabel()

    scrollView.addSubview(bodyLabel)
    bodyLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    bodyLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    bodyLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    bodyLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    bodyLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    bodyLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true

    let heightConstraint = bodyLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.heightAnchor)
    heightConstraint.priority = .defaultLow
    heightConstraint.isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to constrain the `heightAnchor` of the content layout guide and the `UIScrollView` itself to one another:

```
scrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.heightAnchor).isActive = true
```